# Laravel - how to make nested users unique

Tags: laravel

before I will start really hating php and laravel, I'll ask for help

I'm trying to make unique values of users that are part of my offer collection.

This collection is done by relation on users model:

```php
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'messages', 'offer_id', 'from');
}
```

And in controller:

```php
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $offers = Offer::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    foreach ($offers as $offer)
    {
        $offer->users;
    }
    return $offers;
```

This is somehow (?) giving me right result with nested 'users' inside my offer collection.

offer_title
:
(...)

users
:
Array(3)
0
:
{…}
1
:
{…}
2
:
{…}

And this is correct result, except - users are duplicating - because one user can send multiple messages. This is why I'm trying to make them unique this way:

```php
    foreach ($offers as $offer)
    {
        $offer->users = $offer->users->unique()->values()->all();
    }
    return $offers;
```

but this is not working at all. I've tried many configurations. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$offer->users` sets an attribute, you have to use `setRelation()`:

```php
$offer->setRelation('users', $offer->users->unique());
```

Also, you should use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to improve the performance:

```php
$offers = Offer::where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->with('users')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Inspect `dd($offer);` after using `$offer->users = ...`: The unique offers are in `$attributes` but should be in `$relations`. This is why you have to use `setRelation()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir nice, I didn't know this +1.

Comment: @HCK you shouldn't delete your post, it was very informative

Comment: no problem @gileneusz, It was irrelevant for this question, but I've already put that information a couple times out there :)